# Parsing web page with 2 <html> tags

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, python-requests, lxml, xml.etree

I am parsing webpage, with this code

```
s=requests.Session()
response = s.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'})
#Give output of both HTML blocks
tex=response.text

parser=etree.HTMLParser()
tree= etree.parse(StringIO(tex), parser)
result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),pretty_print=True, method="html")
#Give output of first HTML blocks
print result
```

[image: Code for requesting the page and parsing it]

When i `print response.text`, it give an output like this

```
<html><head><script></script></head></html>          
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
</html>
```

Means page has 2 `<html>` tags, now when i run parser it just parses the first `<html>`  block and ignores the second one, so output for

`result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),pretty_print=True, method="html")` is

```
<html><head><script></script></head></html>
```

I need second `<html>` tag not the first one, can you please guide me how to ignore the first `<html>` block and parser second one. I have tried all kind of parsers, none seems to work with it. Can you also explain why is it happening.

Comment: What's the URL of the web page?

Comment: https://www.crisil.com/ratings/credit-ratings-list.jsp?